# Mosquitto Broker on Ubuntu password file error

Tags: ubuntu, mosquitto

I'm on Ubuntu 20 and I added a user to mosquitto with password using the following command:

```
 mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquitto/passwd sammy
```

but when I try the this command:

```
 mosquitto -c passwd
```

I get this error:

```
1608916934: Error: Unknown configuration variable "sammy:$6$3TcIHaVBfJWi1Vfs$cWYwhaVs8bQdvhQt2gIRP9+P8iV2hldheYgF/nWCiCtN+7sfZP5k9tqXAzKUJBkWE2I9/7QzZhwAuHfseH6F6Q==".
1608916934: Error found at passwd:1.
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with configuration since it's system generated file?

**passwd** file content is:

```
sammy:$6$3TcIHaVBfJWi1Vfs$cWYwhaVs8bQdvhQt2gIRP9+P8iV2hldheYgF/nWCiCtN+7sfZP5k9tqXAzKUJBkWE2I9/7QzZhwAuHfseH6F6Q==
```

And  **/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf** content:

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd


#listener 1883 localhost

#listener 8883
#certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/burooq.com/cert.pem
#cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/burooq.com/chain.pem
#keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/burooq.com/privkey.pem


#port 1883
#listener 9001
#listener 8083
#protocol websockets
#certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/burooq.com/cert.pem
#cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/burooq.com/chain.pem
#keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/burooq.com/privkey.pem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-c` option tells `mosquitto` where to find its configuration file. The password file is not the configuration file.

The `Unknown configuration variable` error message is a pretty big hint about this.

The file `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` is the correct configuration file. As you pointed out in your question, you already added a reference to the password file in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf`.